# How to incrementally backup XenServer VMs

Tags: backup, xenserver, snapshot, incremental-backup

I am looking for a way to backup XenServer (or XAPI) VMs

- incrementally. backup just changed data every time.
- without performance penalty, slowing down the server after the backup is done (snapshots do that, right?)
- with possibility to go back in time, not just to the last backup.

I currently use `rdiff-backup` as filesystem-level solution to this problem. However this tool is afaik unmaintained and contains serious bugs.

Comment: I use `rdiff-backup` to do filesystem level and it works without any bugs. Are you looking for alternative to rdiff? try `rsnapshot`

Comment: rsnapshot looks good as a filesystem-level backup. however, I think that rdiff-backup handles changes in big files better (saves delta), rsnapshot uses hardlins and thus is unable to do this efficiently.